# Built HTML editor displaying ‘rectangles’

Tags: javascript, html, css

I programmed an HTML editor, but it isn’t working. It was working a little time ago, but probably my sister edited the code (she practically knows nothing of HTML)

Now the problem is that whenever I press the enter key, instead of simply moving to the next line, a rectangle is created. Why?

Here is the code:

```js
const first = document.querySelector(".first");
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var html = first.textContent;
  iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
});


first.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{
  var html = first.textContent;
  iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
})

first.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
        document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
    });
```

```css
* {
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px black;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100vh;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: 7px solid #36383f;
}

.first {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: pre;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(22, 22, 22);
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  height: 90vh;
}

.second {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: pre;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(22, 22, 22);
  padding: 0.4rem;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-editor">
  <button class="btn">Run</button>
  <div  class="first" contenteditable>writecode</div>
  <iframe class="second" > </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you added `box-shadow` and `border` to all elements.
Remove them from `*`.
I changed `*` to `.first, .second`

```js
const first = document.querySelector(".first");
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var html = first.textContent;
  iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
});


first.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{
  var html = first.textContent;
  iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html);
})

first.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
        document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
    });
```

```css
.first, .second {
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px black;
 position: fixed;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: 7px solid #36383f;
}

.first {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: pre;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(22, 22, 22);
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  height: 90vh;
}

.second {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 50%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: pre;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(22, 22, 22);
  padding: 0.4rem;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-editor">
  <button class="btn">Run</button>
  <div  class="first" contenteditable>writecode</div>
  <iframe class="second" > </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code helped me, but I have some queries. Why did you not include the `btn` in the `*`? Also, why did the enter key produces a rectangle(does it trigger the formation of an element), @NaolChala

Comment: When you press `enter` it creates new `<div>` element

Comment: Ok, Thank you! But still, why didn’t you keep the `btn` in the `*`, @NaolChala